# getting error in python script as TypeError: must be str, not list

Tags: python

I have:

```
objects = [
    {'id': '1FoTrNUISRwlGLAQ9kLOeK', 'path': 'Test/m_TEST', 'type': 'TEMPLATE'},
    {'id': 'erc6CJiluE2jzCxND2bLM1', 'path': 'Test/M_new', 'type': 'TEMPLATE'},
    {'id': 'aqXPJtbQU8ofNxMgfxr7Wk', 'path': 'Test/MCT_Test', 'type': 'MTT'},
    {'id': '8UBPdSfpGHLbwuMbvPWPwQ', 'path': 'Test/P1', 'type': 'PROCESS'},
    {'id': '3vkmrppWY6WbZW8le0ZTWl', 'path': 'Test', 'type': 'Project'}
]
```

How to print `item_type` as

```
['TEMPLATE', 'TEMPLATE', 'MTT', 'PROCESS', 'Project']
```

I tried the following:

```
item_type = items['type']
print(item_type)
```

and its coming as:

```
TEMPLATE
TEMPLATE
MTT
PROCESS
Project
```

Comment: You must have a loop then, please include it.

Comment: `print([o['type'] for o in objects])`

Comment: The duplicate covers this.